# How can I display the current branch in my git-cmd.exe terminal?

Tags: windows, git, terminal

I am using `git-cmd.exe` as my terminal program in Windows 7. How can I configure this to show the current branch in my prompt?

Comment: I believe you can retrieve the branch name with `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` using  Git Bash for Windows. It is the same command you can use elsewhere; see [How to get the current branch name in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6245570/608639) You can change the prompt by setting `$PS1` in `/etc/profile` or you Bash RC file; see [Where exactly Git Bash for Windows' prompt is defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22689548/608639)